# How to get device id with JNI in Android?

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I want to get IMEI from c by `JNI`, I use the code below, but met the error that failed to get `cls`, it always returned `NULL`.I checked env and context, they were all right.Why couldn't me get the `Context` class? I searched from the internet, someone says we should use `java/lang/Object` instead of using `android/context/Context`, I tried this, it works, cls wasn't NULL any longer,but it caused new error when I call `getSystemService`, maybe because common `java/lang/Object` dosn't have this method.Could anyone help me?3Q.

```
char * get_dev_id(JNIEnv *env, jobject context)
{   
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/context/Context");   
    // ---------------- cls == NULL all the time

    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, cls, "TELEPHONY_SERVICE", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring str = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, cls, fid);
    jobject telephony = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, mid, str);
    cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/telephony/TelephonyManager");
    mid =(*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getDeviceId", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    str = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, telephony, mid);
    jsize len = (*env)->GetStringUTFLength(env, str);
    char* deviceId = calloc(len + 1, 1);
    (*env)->GetStringUTFRegion(env, str, 0, len, deviceId);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, str);
    /* to get a string in deviceId */

    return deviceId;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've loaded the jni.so, and the context I passed into the function is the `this.getApplicationContext()` result  of `MainActivity`, am I somewhere wrong?

Comment: I got it, it should be "android/content/Context", not "android/context/Context", looks many one got wrong.