# JNIEnv for get ANDROID_ID from native code

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I need to get Android unique device ID in my native library. As far as i know, it can be done with Java API and i need to use JNI. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972495/how-to-get-device-id-with-jni-in-android), there is similar problem, but different ID is accessed. But this solution needs reference to JNIEnv for getting Java objects/methods. When JNI method called from Java, this is not problem, JNIEnv will be passed from Java. But how i can get JNIEnv for "total" native code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that JNIEnv can be accessed with JavaVM, which can be created with JNI [invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html). By default in Android NDK this functions not exported to user(from platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h):

```
/*
 * VM initialization functions.
 *
 * Note these are the only symbols exported for JNI by the VM.
 */
#if 0  /* In practice, these are not exported by the NDK so don't declare them */
jint JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(void*);
jint JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM**, JNIEnv**, void*);
jint JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(JavaVM**, jsize, jsize*);
#endif
```

But this functions ***presented in /system/lib/libdvm.so*** on my device. After including function definition for JNI_CreateJavaVM in my code and linking to libdvm, copied from device, i got access to creation of JavaVM in Android. This is not recommended, of course, but, if you want it and your device libdvm supports this, you can do it.

Answer (score 3):

The entrypoint of your native activity receives a `struct android_app*` as its argument. `android_app` contains an `ANativeActivity*` named `activity`, which in turn contains a `JNIEnv*` named `env`.

To be able to call Android Java API methods from your native code you'll have to attach the current thread to the VM first, i.e.:

```
JNIEnv *env = state->activity->env;
JavaVM *vm = state->activity->vm;
(*vm)->AttachCurrentThread(vm, &env, NULL);
```

(where `state` is the `struct android_app*`)

Comment: Thank you for response! But it will be helpful in case of native activity. But i am developing native library (not native activity), which can be used from console application, native activity etc.

Comment: Ok. When you said _"in my application"_ and _"application is native"_ I figured you were talking about a native activity. I don't know if there's any way of getting a `JNIEnv` if you're neither using a native activity nor invoking your native code from Java via JNI.